# Why does the word Hypocrite and Spending share same root in Arabic?

Tags: arabic

Why does the word منافقون (Munafiq/hypocrite) and انفاق (Infaq) which means “to spend out (wealth) share the same triliteral root nūn fā qāf (ن ف ق)

[List of occurrences in Quran from triliteral root nūn fā qāf](https://corpus.quran.com/qurandictionary.jsp?q=nfq#(6:35:10))

Comment: This is a question on Arabic language which is not the topic of this site. Further this whole root discussion from my perspective as an Arabic native is meaningless.

Comment: @Medi1Saif https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic : The following, however, are considered off-topic here except where they're shown to be directly relevant to the religion of Islam: ... *The Arabic language itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word نَفِقَ originally comes from the meaning of something passing or being exhausted.

From this comes the sentence نَفِقَتِ الدَّراَهِمُ which means: The dirhams (coins) ran out.

From this comes the word أَنْفَقَ which means to spend money.

The word النَّفَقُ refers to a path that passes through the earth i.e. a tunnel, and it is used to refer to burrows made by mice in the desert.

The burrows of mice have two openings which they enter and exit as they please. From this came the name of مُنافِقِ because he enters Islam from one place and exits it from another.

If he meets a disbeliever, he shows his disbelief from one place. If he meets a believer, he shows his belief.